# Problema para converter data para o padrão brasileiro utilizando JAXB

Tags: java, data, jaxb

Estou com problema ao fazer a conversão do xml em objeto, utilizando JAXB. A data vem no formato `Sun Jan 30 16:08:23 BRT 18`, e quero converter para o formato brasileiro `12-08-2009 16:08:23`.

Classe de conversão do JAXB:

```
public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

    Locale brasil = new Locale("pt", "BR");
    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", brasil);

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
        return dateFormat.format(v);
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception, ParseException {
        return dateFormat.parse(v);
    }

}
```

Comment: É erro ou o *adapter*  não é chamado? O formato da data no seu *date format* tá errado também, no `unmarshal` não vai funcionar, mesmo que ele seja chamado.

Comment: O adapter é chamado. Utilizo a anotação  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class) em cima da variável.